# Why is the vi editor's copy command called Yank?

Tags: vi, history

Why is the vi editor's copy command called “yank”?

Is there any thing significant that can help me to remember the command name?

Comment: Yank is a synonym for pull; you are pulling text to the clipboard... As to why it was called that, `p` was already taken...

Comment: @Seth I have no reference to back that up...

Comment: @jasonwryan, and I doubt you'll find a reference unless you ask Bill Joy! [There is a certain type of question on the topic of history where there doesn't exist any reference except the whim of some long-ago programmer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53110/why-does-the-space-bar-do-page-down-in-browsers/53112#53112), and this is one of them. So you might as well just post the answer because it's the best we're gonna get.

Comment: When I first learned _vi,_ I thought that "yank" was named after the identically named command in [TECO](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04623354). TECO's "yank" read the next page of the input file into the text buffer—not exactly the same as what _y_ does in _vi,_ but similar. I don't really know if it influenced Bill Joy or not, though.

Comment: BTW, there is an entire [StackExchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/search?q=yank&s=bee9dbf3-d288-4012-ba77-ca62df637e38) just for _vi._ Should this question be migrated there?

Comment: And `c` for "copy" is also occupied by the "change" operator. - There's not many unused characters left in `vi`. And the few free ones got later occupied by `vim`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yank is [a synonym for pull](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yank): it captures the concept of pulling text to the buffer or clipboard for later use.

As to why Bill Joy chose to use this term, I can only speculate that as <kbd>p</kbd> was already in use (an abbreviation for put) he wanted an mnemonic that was a single letter (as per the design of vi's progenitor, [ed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) and then [ex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) ) and evocative of the operation.

Comment: Do you think it has somthing to do with Yankee or Yankea ?

Comment: @user2196728 No, yank means to pull: I can't see why it would mean anything else, especially something that has no relationship to the actual operation...

Comment: As yet another item in the great Emacs vs. vi confilct, Emacs calls its _paste_ comand "yank".

Comment: @cjm another "UX Hall of Fame" moment for the OS that lacks only a decent editor...

Comment: Are you saying that the p command predated the yank command?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No, not at all: I am saying that Joy couldn't have both pull and put bound to `p`.

Comment: Emacs version 1, which was written about the same time as vi, already used kill/yank, which it inherited from TECO. TECO dates back to 1962 but I don't know if the first version already had these commands. I found PDP-8 manuals mentioning the yank command, but they may not be the original PDP-8. Nonetheless it seems that “yank” meaning “paste” (the word chosen at Xerox in the mid-1970s, which became the standard when ordinary people got GUIs) was already a thing by the time Joy wrote vi.

Comment: Hmm, yank and pull is evocative of "cut" rather than "copy".

Comment: @jasonwryan And Eight Megabytes And Constantly Swapping. Not that it's quite the impact as it was then... Nor is it as fair a comparison these days. Otoh.. Escape Meta Alt Control Shift is true - though even vim has some of those which I find annoying (well obviously it has ESC but I mean ctrl specifically). Editor wars are beautiful aren't they? Thanks for the laugh - much appreciated.

Comment: As for why yank: I could swear that years ago I read about this on the history of vi but if so I'm unsure where. That being said there is an interview with him about vi (and other things too): https://web.archive.org/web/20120108175421/http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~kirkenda/joy84.html